# Noob Droid Question regarding random number

Tags: android, random

Brand new to droid programming, but would love to learn as much as possible, so I finally got my emulator working correctly, I even got a hello world button to work,

I'm attempting to make this button display a random number, I've googled this and came up with this code:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int n = generator.nextInt(n);
```

I fixed the Random function by including some Random java utility.

I'm assuming this code above goes in the .java file of the project, so my button code looks as follows (tested and works):

```
PopUpText.makeText(v.getContext(), "Hello World", 
PopUpText.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I figured I could replace "Hello World" with n to display the number in the box, however the following error is stopping the compile:

> The local variable n may not have been initialized

Any ideas why this is happening? Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: the new code looks like this:

PopUpText.makeText(v.getContext(), n, 
   PopUpText.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I replaced the 2nd n with 10 and it compiled but caused an unexpected error, code now looks like this int n = generator.nextInt(10);

Comment: You should post more code.  What you've got isn't very helpful for your problem.  The entire onClickListener would be great.  Also post any exceptions you've got from logcat.

Comment: thanks for you time guys! i figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random generator = new Random();
int n = generator.nextInt(n);
```

you using the variable 'n' in its declaration, which is incorrect.

A correct code will read something like this

```
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 100;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out by myself. This code works:

```
Random generator = new Random();                
int n = generator.nextInt(10);

PopUpText.makeText(v.getContext(), "Random Number: "+n, PopUpText.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`int n = generator.nextInt(n);`
n isn't defined, yet